# JavaFX undecorated stage and setMaximized bug

Tags: javafx

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
stage.setMaximized(true);
```

Stage is setted as fullscreen, completely ignoring dock bar (macOS) and task bar (windows) by overlapping on it

Looks like a javafx bug.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't accepted other answers due to the lack of ability to set stage maximized during program execution, so I had to build this mechanism my own. Still, I thank jewelsea and Slaw for providing such informative answers.

Here's my way to fix the issue since it's indeed a bug (it's still not working as expected on windows 11 with javafx version 22):

```
BooleanProperty isStageMaximized = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        isStageMaximized.addListener((a, b, c) -> {
            if (primaryStage.getHeight() == GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height) {
                primaryStage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() / 2);
                primaryStage.setHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight() / 2);
            } else {
                primaryStage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
                primaryStage.setHeight(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height);
            }
            primaryStage.setX(0);
            primaryStage.setY(0);
            primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        });
```

Note that `isStageMaximized` should be a static class field (in order to be accessed across the application). Setting it to true or false makes the stage maximized or not.

Also, I decided to use `GraphicsEnvironment` instead of `Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds()` cause it seems to work great calculating available screen area on other platforms other than windows.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug regarding maximization of undecorated stages on **OS X** that was fixed in JavaFX 22:

- [JDK-8255835 (macOS) Undecorated stage cannot be maximized. Try JDK 22 and verify its behavior.](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8255835)

Similarly, for **Linux** (fixed in JavaFX 16):

- [JDK-8237491 (Linux) Undecorated stage cannot be maximized.](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8237491)

Further developer discussion is on a related pull request:

- [8316419: (macos) Setting X/Y makes Stage maximization not work before show](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/1258)

I tried the example test application from JDK-8255835 on OS X 14.4:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class MaximizedStage extends Application {
    public void start (Stage stage) {
        StackPane sp = new StackPane(new Label("Hello"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene (sp, 500, 500));
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();
        stage.setMaximized(true);
    }
}
```

Using JavaFX 21, the maximized undecorated window was incorrectly shown as size 500x500.

Using JavaFX 22, the maximized undecorated window was correctly shown covering the full screen *except the dock and system menu bar areas, which were still visible*.

Answer (score 2):

## Windows OS

I can reproduce this problem on Windows 11 with both JavaFX 21.0.2 and JavaFX 22. Don't know if the cause is the same, but Swing has apparently had a similar bug for 20+ years:

- [JDK-4737788 - jframe undecorated cover taskbar when maximized](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-4737788).

### Workaround

At least one workaround is to manually set the stage's position and dimensions based on the screen's visual bounds.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(new Label("Hello, World!"))));
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.show();

    /*
     * IMPORTANT: The following must be done on a *showing* stage that has
     *            already been maximized. From testing, it must also be done
     *            each time the stage is maximized. In other words, if you
     *            do setMaximized(false) followed by setMaximized(true),
     *            then you have to set the position/size properties *again*.
     */
    var visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    primaryStage.setX(visualBounds.getMinX());
    primaryStage.setY(visualBounds.getMinY());
    primaryStage.setWidth(visualBounds.getWidth());
    primaryStage.setHeight(visualBounds.getHeight());
  }
}
```

I set each of the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` properties so that it should hopefully work regardless of which side of the screen the task bar is placed. From my limited testing, this works with the task bar on the bottom on Windows 11. Though since Windows 11 does not, as far as I know, let you move the task bar, I have not tested the above when the task bar is on the left, the top, or the right.

The above works great for single-screen setups. If there are multiple screens, then you'll probably have to use one of the `Screen::screensForRectangle` methods to figure out which screen's visual bounds you should use.

#### Other Platforms

This workaround may or may not work on other platforms, assuming you even need the workaround for a given platform and JavaFX version (see [jewelsea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78202542/6395627)).

Comment: *This workaround may or may not work on other platforms.*-> On other platforms (at least on OS X with JavaFX 22), no workaround is required, because the functionality works as expected on those platforms.